# Use fork-and-join in JDK6

Tags: java, java-6, fork-join

As I understand jdk7 has the support for fork-and-join, Can I use fork-and-join in JDK6 without upgraging to JDK7.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup, see [here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) - the package you want is jsr166y.

Comment: Could you please post what flags are required to compile/run some example using this JAR? I'm unable to do so (with JAR in classpath).