# Java Concurrent Iteration: Divide and Conquer vs Runnable for each item

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

When I have hundreds of items to iterate through, and I have to do a computation-heavy operation to each one, I would take a "divide and conquer" approach. Essentially, I would take the processor count + 1, and divide those items into the same number of batches. And then I would execute each batch on a runnable in a cached thread pool. It seems to work well. My GUI task went from 20 seconds to 2 seconds, which is a much better experience for the user.

However, I was reading Brian Goetz' fine book on concurrency, and I noticed that for iterating through a list of items, he would take a totally different approach. He would kick off a Runnable for each item! Before, I always speculated this would be bad, especially on a cached thread pool which could create tons of threads. However each runnable would probably finish very quickly in the larger scope, and I understand the cached thread pool is very optimal for short tasks.

So which is the more accepted paradigm to iterate through computation-heavy items? Dividing into a fixed number of batches and giving each batch a runnable? Or kicking each item off in its own runnable? If the latter approach is optimal, is it okay to use a cached thread pool or is it better to use a bounded thread pool?

Comment: The disadvantage of batching is that if one batch takes longer than the others, you've wasted time because only one CPU will be busy while it completes its work. This is why using individual runnables are better, but I'd recommend using a fixed size thread pool. If your tasks are purely computation, no I/O, then there's little or nothing to gain by creating many threads (there will be no CPU idle time during which other threads can do computation) so fix the thread pool at [processor count] threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With batches you will always have to wait for the longest running batch (you are as fast as the slowest batch). "Divide and conquer" implies management overhead: doing administration for the dividing and monitoring the conquering.

Creating a task for each item is relative straightforward (no management), but you are right in that it may start hundreds of threads (unlikely, but it could happen) which will only slow things down (context switching) if the task does no/very few I/O and is mostly CPU intensive.

If the cached thread pool does not start hundreds of threads (see [getLargestPoolSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getLargestPoolSize%28%29)), then by all means, use the cached thread pool. If too many threads are started then one alternative is to use a bounded thread pool. But a bounded thread pool needs some tuning/decisions: do you use an unbounded task queue or a bounded task queue with a [CallerRunsPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) for example?

On a side note: there is also the [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) which is suitable for tasks that start sub-tasks.

Comment: Yes F/J is easier. You can set your threshold to a small number for batch size. Instead of one task per element (which could mean a lot of tasks) put in two, three etc. and experiment a bit.

Comment: I keep hearing about ForkJoin, it sounds like I may have practical use for it now.

Comment: It has its problems but for simple splitting and executing compute-only tasks it works well.

Comment: Too bad my company is still on Java 6, even though there is no good reason to be. Id use F/J otherwise

Comment: @ThomasN. Java 6 does not have to be a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205874/use-fork-and-join-in-jdk6