# fork/join alternative for java 6

Tags: java, java-6, fork-join

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205874/use-fork-and-join-in-jdk6), `ForkJoinPoll` can be somehow ported to Java6. However, using openjdk javac 1.6.0_34 I'm unable to compile without warnings any example with described JAR in classpath or run it (`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jsr166y/RecursiveTask : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`).

So is there any alternative for fork/join model available for Java6?

Comment: Did you see if akka or Reactor works with JDK6?

Comment: If you downloaded the jar file explicitly mentioned to be compiled with Java 6 javac, you should contact the webmaster because then the jar is buggy.  In the mean time you may be able to get an older, working copy from the Internet Archive, or simply download the source and compile it yourself.

Comment: How about using Future/FutureTask instead of fork/join?

Comment: @Jayan it seems like Akka works with Java6 well, however I'm looking for precisely the same API as Java7 introduced. Nevermind, I was just wondering whether some working solution is publicly known :)

Comment: Okay.  Error indicate you did not use _JDK6_  to compile the jar.