# Recursion-aware ThreadPool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, concurrency

I've been looking for a java thread-pool that is "recursive aware". In other words, if I create a fixed thread pool with a fixed size of N and then submit N tasks, everything is okay, as long as these tasks do not, in turn, submit additional tasks to the thread-pool and then wait for the results. As soon as that occurs, my ThreadPool, created with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads), hangs and never completes, because my ThreadPool is saturated and no waiting tasks cannot be allocated for execution because all threads in the pool are busy waiting for them to complete.

I realize that this sounds paranoid, but I have a case where I have a computation-intensive application, where at one point, I have 16,000 tasks that can be naively executed in parallel. There is no communication or synchronization between threads - I just need to wait for them to finish executing. The issue, is, each of these 16,000 tasks can be broken into some X number of tasks that can again be executed in parallel with no communication or synchronization necessary between each other.

The danger/concern is that someone would decide to attempt to parallelize this second level of steps, which would very reasonably block my ThreadPool.

Is there any library that would create and manage a ThreadPool that would identify that I am already executing in a thread that belongs to the thread-pool and then schedule the tasks automatically to be executed in the current thread rather than waiting for the task to be submitted to the ThreadPool (but only for the case where the ThreadPool is already saturated and has a backlog of tasks waiting to execute?

I've implemented a very crude demo/proof-of-concept, but it would be much happier if there was standard, tested, accepted implementation available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem sounds tailor made for the [Fork/Join pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) introduced in Java 7.

> The fork/join framework is an implementation of the ExecutorService interface that helps you take advantage of multiple processors. It is designed for work that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively

Comment: Sadly, I am stuck with Java 6, for the time being.

Comment: [There is a backport.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205874/use-fork-and-join-in-jdk6)

Comment: @NathanKummer for what you want to do, you really should be using Java 8 which has parallelStream() which uses Fork/Join and is almost certainly the right tool for the job.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `workSteaingPool` from [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), which returns `ForkJoinPool`.

```
static ExecutorService  newWorkStealingPool()
```

> Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.

Advantage of using this API : Till java 7, if you are using `ForkJoinPool`, you have to divide the tasks into `RecursiveAction` and `RecursiveTask`. But with Java 8, you can use newWorkStealingPool() as a ExecutorService itself which hids all complexities.

This factory method is part of Java 8 and returns an executor of type ForkJoinPool which works slightly different than normal executors. Instead of using a fixed size thread-pool ForkJoinPools are created for a given parallelism size which per default is the number of available cores of the hosts CPU.

Have a look at this [article](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) on usage.