# How to divide a huge loop into multiple threads and then add result in collection?

Tags: multithreading, java-6

I am performing some task in a loop. I need to divide this loop of 1.2 million into multiple threads. Each thread will have some result in list. When all threads are completed I need to add all threads list data into one common list. I can not use ExecutorService. How can I do this?

It should be compatible to jdk 1.6.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
int elements = 1200000;

public  void function1() {

        int oneTheadElemCount = 10000;
        float fnum_threads  =  (float)elements / (float)oneTheadElemCount ;
        String s = String.valueOf(fnum_threads);
        int num_threads = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."))) + 1 ;

        for(int count =0 ; count < num_threads ; count++) {
            int endIndex = ((oneTheadElemCount * (num_threads - count)) + 1000) ;
            int startindex = endIndex - oneTheadElemCount ;

            if(count == (num_threads-1) )
            {
                startindex = 0;
            }
            if(startindex == 0 && endIndex > elements) {
                endIndex = elements -1 ;
            }

            dothis( startindex,endIndex);
        }

        for(Thread t : threads) {
            t.run();
        }
    }

public List dothis(int startindex,  int endIndex) throws  Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = startindex; 
                    (i < endIndex && (startindex < elements && elements) ) ; i++) 
            {
                //task adding elements in list      
            }                
        }
    });        
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Looked into parallell streams?

Comment: Read up on fork/join, or Spliterators in Java 8.

Comment: it should be compatible with jdk1.6

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What were the results of the research and how do those results fail to work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Java you are using but in Java 7 and higher, you can use Fork/Join [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Basically,

> Fork/Join, introduced in Java 7, isn't intended to replace or compete
>   with the existing concurrency utility classes; instead it updates and
>   completes them. Fork/Join addresses the need for divide-and-conquer,
>   or recursive task-processing in Java programs (see Resources).
>
> Fork/Join's logic is very simple: (1) separate (fork) each large task
>   into smaller tasks; (2) process each task in a separate thread
>   (separating those into even smaller tasks if necessary); (3) join the
>   results.

[Citation](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078440/enterprise-java/java-tip-when-to-use-forkjoinpool-vs-executorservice.html).

There are various [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html) online that can help with it. I haven't used it myself.

I hope this helps.

---

For Java6, you can follow this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205874/use-fork-and-join-in-jdk6).

Comment: it should be compatible to jdk 1.6

Comment: Unfortunately in Java 6 you will have to write your own ForkJoinPool.